# Singleton resources shared by several MVC controllers in Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller, servlets, spring-mvc, singleton

Is there a way to have a singleton resource used by multiple controllers?

We got 2 servlets, each one with its own application contexts: one-servlet.xml & two-servlet.xml and lib-context.xml with singleton bean "util".

Now, if we import lib-context.xml into each of 2 servlet contexts above, spring will create a separate application context for each servlet and we'll end up with 2 singletone objects.

Is there a way to configure application that only one singleton object will be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In your `web.xml`, load `lib-context.xml` with the `ContextLoaderListener` instead of loading it with the `DispatcherServlet`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/lib-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

You can remove the imports from your servlet-specific app context configuration files.

All the `DispatcherServlet`s will see not only the shared `lib-context.xml` above but also any contexts that they themselves load.

(You may need to adjust the `param-value` example I gave. That path is just an example.)